# AngularJS - Three dependent selects - only the first two populate

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, pug, trello

I am working with Express, Angular, and Jade. The relevant piece of the application allows the user to select an organization, board, and list from their Trello account. The three items form a hierarchy: Organizations contain boards, and boards contain lists.

So in my jade partial, I have the following:

```
select(ng-model='userData.apps.trello.organization', ng-options='orgId as orgDetails.name for (orgId, orgDetails) in orgsandboards')
select(ng-model='userData.apps.trello.board', ng-options='boardId as boardDetails.name for (boardId, boardDetails) in orgsandboards[userData.apps.trello.organization]["boards"]')
select(ng-model='userData.apps.trello.list', ng-options='listId as listDetails.name for (listId, listDetails) in orgsandboards[userData.apps.trello.organization][userData.apps.trello.board]["lists"]')
```

Syntax for the above, by the way, came from [this helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18651943/angularjs-dependent-dropdowns-storing-one-value-in-model-using-other-as-sour).

Anyhow, the data structure - modeled on the answer above - looks like this:

```
orgsandboards: {
    orgid1: {
        name: "organization 1",
        boards: {
            boardid1: {
                name: "name of the first board",
                lists: {
                    listid1: {
                        name: "name of list 1"
                    },
                    listid2: {
                        name: "name of list 2"
                    }
                }
            },
            boardid2: {
                name: "name of the second board",
                lists: {
                    listid3: {
                        name: "name of list 3"
                    },
                    listid4: {
                        name: "name of list 4"
                    }
                }                
            }
        }
    },
    orgid2: {.. and so on ..}
}
```

The first two selects work great. If I change the organization, the list of potential boards also changes. However, the third select - lists - never updates. I have verified that the data is present and available.

I've looked through other questions and answers, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17700734/switching-data-models-in-angularjs-for-dynamic-select-menus) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082609/angularjs-populating-dependent-combobox). As happens so often here, none seems to offer the answer I seek.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a case of Angular's forgiving nature masking an error.  The third list's `ng-options` needs to end in:

```
in orgsandboards[userData.apps.trello.organization]["boards"][userData.apps.trello.board]["lists"]
```

notice the `["boards"]` part.

The way you currently have it, you're referencing a key in in `orgsandboards[userData.apps.trello.organization]` that doesn't exist, but Angular doesn't usually throw errors in those circumstances--it just fails silently.

Comment: I know it would be something simple. Thank you!